# Two App scripts running on Forms and Sheets, need to connect them both

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have an onboarding form that puts all the responses in a google sheet which has an app script running to add user to google admin and different groups by taking in values from the last row of the sheet. That works fine, it's just that I have to run the script every time the form is filled so I want to create a form trigger.

It made sense to create a form submit trigger on the app script attached to the google form and I added the library and script id of the other appscipt and pulled in a method from there like such

```
// Create a form submit installable trigger
// using Apps Script.
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {

  // Get the form object.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Since we know this project should only have a single trigger
  // we'll simply check if there are more than 0 triggers. If yes,
  // we'll assume this function was already run so we won't create
  // a trigger.
  var currentTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(currentTriggers.length > 0)
    return;
  
  // Create a trigger that will run the onFormSubmit function
  // whenever the form is submitted.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function onFormSubmit() {
  wait(7000);
  AddingUserAutomation.createUserFromSheets()
}
```

The trouble is I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null
    at createUserFromSheets(Code:43:19)
```

My createUserFromSheets function is taking the active sheet

```
function createUserFromSheets(){
  let data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let row  = data.getLastRow();

  let firstname = data.getRange(row,2).getValue();
  let lastname = data.getRange(row,3).getValue();
... etc etc 
}
```

I think it is unable to pull the getActiveSheet part that is why I had added the wait() function on formSubmit() but it still would not work.

Is there a way to solve this or a better way to do it?

```
function createWorkspaceUser(recentResponse) {
  console.log("Creating account for:\n"+recentResponse[1]);
  debugger;
  var user = {"primaryEmail": recentResponse[0] + '.' + recentResponse[1] + '@' + recentResponse[3],
              "name": {
                "givenName": recentResponse[0],
                "familyName": recentResponse[1]
              },
              "password": newPassword(),
              };
  try {
    user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
    console.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
  }catch(err) {
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

I am doing it this way but it's running an error on primaryemail

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `let row  = sheet.getLastRow();`?  Same for next 2 lines of code.

Comment: Yes that is right, my apologies!

Comment: @TheWizEd `let data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` data is a sheet

Comment: @Cooper Yes it's the sheet where the last row values are being pulled and creating the user

Comment: Is `AddingUserAutomation` a library?

Comment: In an onFormSubmit for a form there may not be an active sheet

Comment: Yes, AddingUserAutomation is a library connected to the sheet where data is being pulled. How do I add the sheet to my onFormSubmit method

Comment: Use openById() and the n getSheetByName()

Comment: Why not just skip the library part? You can have the onFormSubmit in the script file of the sheet itself.. all the logic in one place??

Comment: I tried that at first but then form is being filled and responses are being recorded in google sheets from where the user values are being taken. So when I had it in one place, either the trigger wasn't working or the values weren't being filled properly

Comment: I tried the openById() and then getSheetByName() method, it will still return null on the formSubmit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion [NEW UPDATE]

> *As mentioned by [RemcoE33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13461183/remcoe33)*

To have a more simplified setup, perhaps skip the library part and do all the scripting ([bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_sheets)) in your **Google Form** itself.

Since we don't have the complete overview of your actual Google Form. See this sample below as a reference:

### Google Form Script

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var count = 0;
  var recentResponse = [];
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  for (var i in formResponses) {
    count += 1;
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      if(formResponses.length === count){ //Process only the recently submitted response
        var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
        recentResponse.push(itemResponse.getResponse())
      }
    }
  }
  createWorkspaceUser(recentResponse);
}

function createWorkspaceUser(recentResponse){
  var user = {"primaryEmail": recentResponse[0].replace(/\s/g, '') + '.' + recentResponse[1].replace(/\s/g, '') + '@' +recentResponse[3],
              "name": {
              "givenName": recentResponse[0],
              "familyName": recentResponse[1]
              },
              "password":newPassword(),
             };

  try{
    user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
    Logger.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
  }catch (err) {
    Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }

  console.log(user);
}
```

> **NOTE**: You no longer need to build an `on form submit` trigger since the `onFormSubmit()` function will automatically run right after hitting the submit button.

## Demonstration

**1. Submit user data from sample form:**

> [image]

**2. Test user account will be created on Workspace Admin Console Users:**

> [image]

### Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: @beforesunset_mj I hope this helps. If there's anything missing, don't hesitate to comment

Comment: Thank you so much Irvin, let me try this out and get back to you soon!

Comment: I edited my answer with the issue i am having

Comment: @beforesunset_mj Will you be able to share a screenshot of your Google Form? & What is the exact error with the primary email?

Comment: Hey I added screenshots, please let me know what I am doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: @beforesunset_mj are the domains listed on your Form section `Email Domains` were added as a secondary domain in your Google Workspace Admin Console? ALSO, please share the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: @beforesunset_mj Do you get this error `Failed with error API call to directory.users.insert failed with error: Invalid Input: primary_user_email`? If it is, please try the updated `createWorkspaceUser(recentResponse)` function on my answer as I've added a section that will remove all **possible white-spaces** on the user primary email on this line `recentResponse[0].replace(/\s/g, '') + '.' + recentResponse[1].replace(/\s/g, '') + '@' +recentResponse[3]`.

Comment: Hi Irvin, thanks a lot! It's working fine now!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132591/how-to-add-multiple-user-attributes-in-app-script

Comment: Can you help me out with this, please?