# How to add multiple user attributes in app-script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am automating the onboarding process in our organization and have a google form connected with app-script. The user is getting created in google admin but I would like to add more attributes such as Manager's name, Department, phone number etc.

Here is the API method:

```js
var user = {
  "primaryEmail": email,
  "name": {
    "givenName": givenName,
    "familyName": familyName
  },
  "relations": [{
    "value": manager,
    "type": manager,
  }],
  "password": password,
};

console.log(password);

try {
  user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
  console.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
}
```

But as of now, there is something wrong with the manager code because I get the following error:

```
Failed with error API call to directory.users.insert failed with error: Invalid value for: TEST is not a valid value
```

(For context, I had put in TEST as the manager's value in the form)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong so I can fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: Is ```"relations": [{
    "value": manager,
    "type": manager,
  }]``` a custom schema? or are you using the default ```'Manager's email``` attribute in the Admin Console? If the latter, that field will only take full email addresses existent in the Google Workspace environment, can you try entering a correct email address as value and share the outcome?

Comment: Hi, it's the latter and I put in a company email address and got this error "Failed with error API call to directory.users.insert failed with error: Invalid Input: Bad request for " It just ends like that without further information.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users) it states:

> "... relations: A list of the user's relationships to other users..."

As for relation value types:

1. type accepts values:

   admin_assistant, assistant, brother, child, custom, domestic_partner, dotted_line_manager, exec_assistant, father, friend, manager, mother, parent, partner, referred_by, relative, sister, spouse

Custom: Let's you add custom values.

2. values refer to the person the user is related to. It can be a name or an email address as seen below.

In the onboarding scenario, this can be implemented to specify the manager's email address for this user:

```
let email = 'GIMMEABREAK@domain.xyz'
let givenName = 'X'
let familyName = 'testOnly'
let password = 'passowerd#$"#$22'


let type = 'manager'
let value = 'yancymelany@domain.xyz'

var user = {
  "primaryEmail": email,
  "name": {
    "givenName": givenName,
    "familyName": familyName
  },
  "relations": [{
    "value": value,
    "type": type,
  }],
  "password": password,
};
```

And this succeeds:

[image]

[image]